# Spring boot security principal user getting changed to newly logged in user details

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Am using spring boot 2.2.4 with spring security. And the problem am facing is every time am logging in with a new user the principal username is getting reset to the newly logged in user's details, Why. However as I have observed the session ID remains correct. I don't understand this behavior. Any idea ?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class IctSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                //URLs matching for access rights
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signin").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ict/**/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/queue/reply").hasAnyAuthority(RolesConst.APP_USER)
                .antMatchers("/find").hasAnyAuthority(RolesConst.APP_USER)
                //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                //form login
                .csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .and()
                //logout
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        //return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

UserDetails service

```
@Service
public class IctUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override 
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException { 
        //return new IctUserDetails(username);
        Optional<UserEntity> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + username));
        //UserController.groupname(username);
        return user.map(IctUserDetails::new).get();
    }

}
```

UserDetails class

```
   public class IctUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static String username;
    private String password;

    private List<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;


    public IctUserDetails() {
    }

    public IctUserDetails(UserEntity userEntity) {
        this.username = userEntity.getUsername();


        this.password = userEntity.getPassword();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authoriteis = getRoleAuthoritiesFromUserEntity(userEntity);
        this.authorities = authoriteis;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of role authorities from current user entity
     * @param userRoleEntities
     * @return
     */
    @Transactional
    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getRoleAuthoritiesFromUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {
        Collection<UserRoleEntity> userRoleEntities = userEntity.getUserRoleEntities();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authoriteis = userRoleEntities
                .stream()
                .map(ur -> ur.getRole().getRoleName())
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return authoriteis;
    }

}
```

Comment: Never use `static` unless you can explain why: `IctUserDetails.username`.

Comment: @chrylis -on strike- hi, yes that was the mistake. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: So can @chrylis-onstrike- or Bhadabyuti please add this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

So, this was the problem. I had declared username in my UserDetails class as static 
`public static String username;`.

I have changed this to `private String username;` and all is good now. Thanks.